# CentOS: Apache cannot see the NAS drive

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I have a new CentOS installation which I'm setting up as a new local dev machine. My files are on a NAS & I've setup access to the NAS on '/var/www/websites/' using the mount command.

I can 'ls /var/www/websites/' and see a list of files. But when I put this into the Apache configuration file, I get the message "Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/websites/website.co.uk/htdocs] does not exist"

My configuration file is setup as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev.website.co.uk
  ServerAlias *.example.org
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error,log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/websites/website.co.uk/htdocs
  <Directory "/var/www/websites/website.co.uk/htdocs">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone offer help please?

Comment: Can you provide the output of: `namei -l /var/www/websites/website.co.uk/htdocs` .   If that returns `No such file or directory`, can you provide the output of `find /var/www/websites/ -type d`.     Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

My solution - install Webmin and setup Apache using this! I dunno why yet, but it now works...